# Forming a list of significant results in R

Tags: r, list, data-manipulation

The code below computes a list of results (in this case one result, with 6 components) that are either significant to varying degrees (marked by *** in this case) or not. How can I make a new list of only the significant results? Specifically I would like to keep all 6 components of the result/s provided that the value for TE is significant in the X --> Y direction, whether or not the same is true for the opposite direction, Y --> X. As the example below meets this criterion, it would form part of my new list:

```
install.packages("RTransferEntropy")
library(RTransferEntropy)
set.seed(12345)
n <- 2500
x <- rep(0, n + 1)
y <- rep(0, n + 1)

for (i in 2:(n + 1)) {
  x[i] <- 0.2 * x[i - 1] + rnorm(1, 0, 2)
  y[i] <- x[i - 1] + rnorm(1, 0, 2)
 }

x <- x[-1]
y <- y[-1]
library(future)
# enable parallel processing for all future transfer_entropy calls
plan(multiprocess)
set.seed(12345)
shannon_te <- transfer_entropy(x, y)
shannon_te
```

Thanks!